# PHP Regex using the \Q \E syntax

Tags: php, regex

I am reading up on [regex's](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) and it says: `All the characters between the \Q and the \E are interpreted as literal characters. E.g. \Q*\d+*\E matches the literal text *\d+*.`

So I tested this out:

```
$pattern = '/\Q~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{?><,./\][":';\E/';
$string = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{?><,./\][":';';
preg_match( $pattern, $string, $matches );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($matches);
echo "</pre>";
```

It gives me the error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '~' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/xampp/web_development/new_study_2014/regex.php on line 3
```

Why is this not working as stated above?

Comment: Look at the syntax highlighting. Notice anything odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to quote your `'` inside the patterns:

```
$pattern = '/\Q~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{?><,./\][":';\E/';
           ^--start string #1             ^--end string #1
                                               ^--start string #2
$string = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{?><,./\][":';';
          ^---end of string #2
           ^---your error, because it's OUTSIDE of a string
```

Comment: Ok so I updated as follows: $pattern = '/\Q~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{?><,./\][":\';\E/';    $string = '~!@#$%^&*()_+|}{?><,./\][":\';';

Comment: But gives me a: `Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '\' in`

Comment: yes, because you also have an unescaped `/` in your pattern too. e.g. you should learn basic regex syntax before trying something this complicated.